# Change the position of prefab based on the device type

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am trying to move a prefab in another part of my canvas based on if it's for the IPHONE or ANDROID. I have the following:

```
public Image accessoryImage;

  public void OnStart() 
  {
#if UNITY_IPHONE
  accessoryImage.transform.position = accessoryImage.transform.position + new Vector3(10.0f, -269.0f, 0.0f);
#endif      
  }
```

I keep getting the error:

```
object reference not set to an instance of an object
```

Answer (score 0):

`accessoryImage` is probably NOT initialized. Make sure something is assigned to it in the Editor. You have to initialize `accessoryImage` before you can use it.

If you want to initialize it from code you could do it like this:

```
public void OnStart() 
{
  Image accessoryImage = GameObject.Find("NAMEOFGAMEOBJECT").GetComponent<Image>();
  if (accessoryImage == null)
  {
  Debug.Log("Image is not assigned");
  return; //Exit
  }
  accessoryImage.transform.position = accessoryImage.transform.position + new Vector3(10.0f, -269.0f, 0.0f);
}
```

NAMEOFGAMEOBJECT = the name of GameObject `Image` is attached to in the Editor.